# grouping documents of collection in mongodb based on combination of fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in which subject and student are unique fields and I will be saving field called rank for that combination in particular date. So I want to group data by date based on that combination. I am using node js, mongodb. Could anyone answer my query.

Sample documents:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-30", "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"), "subject" : "physics", "rank" : 9 }, 
{ "_id" : 2, "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-26", "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"), "subject" : "physics", "rank" : 12 },
{ "_id" : 3, "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-12", "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"), "subject" : "physics", "rank" : 10 }
```

Expected Output:

```
{ "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"), "subject": "physics", "ranks": [{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-12", "rank":10},{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-26", "rank":12},{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-30", "rank":9},] }
```

Comment: Can you show some sample documents and expected json output ? Don't forget to add what you have tried to the post.

Comment: @Veeram Sample documents:{
    "_id" : "1",
    "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-30",
    "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"),
    "subject" : "physics",
    "rank" : 9
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-26",
    "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"),
    "subject" : "physics",
    "rank" : 12
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "createdDateStr" : "2018-09-12",
    "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"),
    "subject" : "physics",
    "rank" : 10
}

Comment: @Veeram Expected Output:
{
    "student" : ObjectId("5b9661a7ffc73a683d4c0ded"),
    "subject": "physics",
    "ranks": [{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-12", "rank":10},{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-26", "rank":12},{"createdDateStr" : "2018-09-30", "rank":9},]
}

Comment: Use `db.colname.aggregate({$group:{_id:{ "student" : "$student, "subject": "$subject"}, "ranks":{$push:{"createdDateStr" : "$createdDateStr", "rank":"$rank"}}}})`

Comment: It works `db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: {
      "student": "$student",
      "subject": "$subject"
    },
    "ranks": {
      $push: {
        "createdDateStr": "$createdDateStr",
        "rank": "$rank"
      }
    }
  }
})` He forgot to add `"` only

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It worked but it throws error for large data. Error is as follows "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in". Do you have any idea of how to pass allowDiskUse: true in query.